# CakePHP find 3 same records then continue with following 3 records

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a model called Task with the following fields:

1. `trade_id`
2. `site_id`
3. `third_email_alert_date`

I am trying to do a find() on the Task model where there are 3 tasks with the same `site_id` and `trade_id` as the corresponding request data, I will then send out an email and populate the `third_email_alert_date` field.

So in essence it should do the following:

1. Find the last 3 tasks with the same `trade_id` and `site_id`
2. Send an email and populate `third_email_alert_date` with the date of when the email was sent
3. Start counting again from records after the one where `third_email_alert_date` is set.

Here is what I have:

Task Conditions:

```
                    $task_conditions = array(
                        'Task.trade_id' => $this->request->data['Task']['trade_id'],
                        'Task.site_id' => $this->request->data['Task']['site_id']
                    );
```

Order by created date in descending so that we have the newest tasks first:

```
                    $tasks= $this->Task->find('all', array(
                        'conditions' => $task_conditions,
                        'order' => 'created DESC'
                        )
                    );
```

This gives me all the records where `trade_id` and `site_id` are matching and orders by most recently created first.

I can't seem to figure out how I can find the last 3 and do the counting again from the newly updated record. Any ideas?

Comment: you can `'order' => 'modified DESC'` and `'limit' => 3`

Comment: I can't order by `modified` because another field on the task may be modified at any time so this then won't work as I need to check for the `third_email_alert_date`

Comment: then you may add a new field like `email_sent type DATETIME` where you can store datetime ORDER and LIMIT your query

Comment: I already have that called `third_email_alert_date`? but then how it would I preserve how it counts the records?

Answer (score 0):

Set a TINYINT field that defaults to false.  When an email is sent mark the three that had email sent as true then in your find just include the email sent field.

```
$tasks= $this->Task->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => $task_conditions + ['email_sent' => false],
    'order' => 'created DESC'
    )
);
```

Or if you need the date just mark all three with the date and then change sort condition for date_field => null